# How do I write a Django template custom tag that adds a slash before a single quote?

Tags: python, django, templates

Am I doing this right? (probably not...someone correct? thanks)

```
@register.filter('addslashes')
@stringfilter
def addslashes(text, arg):
    return text.replace('\'','\\'')


{{ query|addslashes }}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? A pretty sure fire way to see if you're doing it right or not is to see if it works.

Comment: Try it and tell us the error if it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a builtin filter with the exact same name: [addslashes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#addslashes)

It also escapes double quotes, and double slashes. If you only want single quotes, you will have to adapt it and name it differently.

Here is how the original works:

```
def addslashes(value):
    """
    Adds slashes before quotes. Useful for escaping strings in CSV, for
    example. Less useful for escaping JavaScript; use the ``escapejs``
    filter instead.
    """
    return value.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", "\\'")
addslashes.is_safe = True
addslashes = stringfilter(addslashes)
```